# How to update multiple projects based on one CMS

Tags: php, workflow

I have a general questions about the workflow. Looking for an advice how to manage my projects in a best way.
I have my own CMS that im developing
Lets say it is in version 2 in the moment.
I have the main, mother copy of the CMS on my localhost.
I have also about 5 other clients sites that are using this CMS.
I have 5 different directories on my localhost for each project. They are in sync with 5 different clients servers.
Now what I want is:
1. When doing some changes to the file on my mother copy of the cms i would liker to update with one click all localhost copies of the the same cms version and also all server copies of that cms.
2. When doing some changes on one of the client CMS I would like the same, copy these changes to other CMS copies from localhost, and servers. 
Now i'm doing this manually and this is very time consuming.

Do you have some advice, maybe some article, tutorial about how to manage projects that way? Is GIT something I should check or maybe some other solutions?
I'm using SublimeText3 for developing. PHP, Js and mysql.