# Yii2 how to update other projects when base project is updated?

Tags: php, yii2, web-deployment

We currently have `Yii2` base project (we can say, like, project root from which we will create other projects). Right now there are several modules, models, controllers and viewers. Everything is fine here but **how to deploy (and where) so that when we update base project, all child projects that were using our base project would be updated (best is through Composer with composer update).**

For example, [Kartik](http://demos.krajee.com/) has its plugins/widgets and we can simply update through Composer with command like `$ php composer.phar require kartik-v/yii2-grid "@dev"`.

So we want to have something similar, but not accessible publicly (so that random people couldn't access without some sort of email/username/password). This part is not as important as the first part because in this part we at least can use something like [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/). There aren't many possible solutions, most likely a few only, actually, but it's a challenge that we cannot solve right now.

*I have tried StackExchange but it's not as popular StackOverflow, so I'm trying to give as much information as I can. Assuming I see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21622415/how-to-update-multiple-projects-based-on-one-cms), this question shouldn't be off-topic either. Thanks!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use your own private repository for keeping yii2 app template. To update all your projects use composer. Here's code example:

```
"repositories": [
    {
      "type":"package",
      "package": {
        "name": "repo-name/yii2template",
        "version":"master",
        "source": {
          "url": "https://your-git-server.com/repo-name/yii2template.git",
          "type": "git",
          "reference":"master"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
```

So when you make changes to your template, you just update composer for certain project and get those changes.

P.S. Another idea is Ansible. You can update child projects by this tool, but you have to write playbook manually for your needs. 
If you need this template local only, you could use PhpStorm, it can make templates from project.